# I want to get the insights of the image stored on the Softlayer cloud WITHOUT DOWNLOADING IT LOCALLY using ibm watson Visual Recognition

Tags: java, image, ibm-watson, ibm-cloud-infrastructure, visual-recognition

I want to do some Analytics on the image hosted on the cloud using IBM Watson Visual recognition. Currently I am downloading the image and storing it locally and then give it to the Watson visual Recognition service. **I dont want to download the image locally**.I am using JAVA

Comment: The image needs to be local to the machine which does the processing.  You could pay them to do the processing for you so you don't need to download them.

Answer (score 1):

In order to [create classifiers](https://www.ibm.com/smarterplanet/us/en/ibmwatson/developercloud/visual-recognition/api/v2/#create_a_classifier) with Visual Recognition, you do not need to download the images locally; you only need to call the endpoint with the positive and negative examples. I suggest writing a script to gather the image data, zip it up, and then call the classifier creation endpoint *from a server in the cloud*.

Comment: thanks sir, But the query is that the image is sitting on a softlayer cloud so firstly I need to download it and then upload to watson service . I dont want to download the image locally

Answer (score 1):

Currently the functionality you are requesting is not possible today.

I've added it to our backlog, as your request makes complete sense!